# Proving $\text{Cov}((X,Y))^2 \leq \text{Var}(X) \text{Var}(Y)$ with Cauchy-Schwarz

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I've been trying to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to prove that
\begin{equation*}
\text{Cov}(X,Y)^2 \leqslant \text{Var}(x) \cdot \text{Var}(Y).
\end{equation*}

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality can be expressed as follows:

If $u$ and $v$ are vectors in an inner product space, then $\langle u,v \rangle^2 \leqslant \|u\|^2 \|v\|^2$.

How do you define the vectors and the inner product so to prove the result in the first sentence. I've seen something like
\begin{equation*}
\text{Cov}(X,Y)^2
\leqslant \langle x - E(X), y - E(Y) \rangle
\leqslant \|x - E(X)\|^2 \|y - E(Y)\|^2
= \text{Var}(X) \cdot \text{Var}(Y),
\end{equation*}
but how is $\langle x - E(X), y - E(Y) \rangle$ expressed as a sum? Also how can you let $x - E(X)$ and $y - E(Y)$ be vectors?

Any insight would be great.

Answer (score 5):

The inner product space you might have in mind is $L^2(\Omega, \mathscr A, P)$, the space of all square integrable random variables $X \colon \Omega \to \mathbb R$. Square integrable means that we have 
\[ \|X\|^2 := E(|X|^2) = \int_{\Omega} |X|^2\, dP < \infty \]
The inner product is given by 
\[
 \left<X,Y\right> := \int_\Omega XY\, dP. 
\]
So it isn't a sum, but an integral and the vectors are the elements of the vector space $L^2(\Omega)$, that is, random variables.

Cauchy-Schwarz reads 
\[
 \int_\Omega XY\, dP = \left<X,Y\right> \le \|X\|^2 \|Y\|^2 = \int_\Omega X^2\, dP \cdot \int_\Omega Y^2\, dP
\]
and applying this to $X-E(X)$ and $Y - E(Y)$ gives the desired inequality.

---

In cases where $P$ is discrete, that is there is a countable subset $\Omega'$ of $\Omega$ with $P(\Omega') = 1$, the integrals are sums, in this case we have 
\[
  \left<X,Y\right> = \int_\Omega XY\, dP = \sum_{\omega \in \Omega'} X(\omega)Y(\omega) 
\]
and 
\[ \left\|X\right\|^2 = \sum_{\omega \in \Omega'} X(\omega)^2. \]

---

$\def\cov{\operatorname{cov}}$
Addendum after comment: As you write, for discrete random variables we have 
\[
  \cov(X,Y) = \sum_{\omega\in \Omega} \bigl( X(\omega) - E(X)\bigr)\bigl(Y(\omega) - E(Y)\bigr)
\]
If we want to write this as a sum over the values of $X$ and $Y$, just note that the joint probability mass (or as you write density) function $p_{X,Y}$ is given by 
\[
  p_{X,Y}(x,y) = P({\omega \mid X(\omega) = x, Y(\omega) = y})
\]
Grouping these terms in the above sum, we obtain
\[
\cov(X,Y) = \sum_{x\in X[\Omega]}\sum_{y\in Y[\Omega]} \bigl(x- E(X)\bigr)\bigl(y-E(Y)\bigr)p_{X,Y}(x,y).
\]

Comment: Sorry about late comment. Thanks for your answer. For discrete RVs you have $cov(X,Y) = /sum_{\omega \in \Omega'} (X(\omega)-E(X(\omega)))(Y(\omega)-E(Y(\omega)))$. Is this equivalent to

Comment: IGNORE ABOVE! Sorry about late comment. Thanks for your answer. For discrete RVs you have $cov(X,Y) = \sum_{\omega \in \Omega'} (X(\omega)-E(X(\omega)))(Y(\omega)-E(Y(\omega)))$. Is this equivalent to $\sum_{x \in R}\sum_{y \in M} (x-E(X)(y-E(Y) p_{X,Y}(x,y)$ where the RV $X$ takes values $x$ in a set $R$ and the RV $Y$ takes values $y$ in a set $M$ and $p_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is the joint prob. density function of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: @SamForbes Yes, added something about this in my answer above.

Comment: great, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The cauchy-schwarz inequality is for discrete case, (∑ (a_i)^2 ) (∑ (b_i)^2 ) ≥ ( ∑ (a_i)(b_i) ) ^2  , where the sum is over the suffix i from 1 to n ( n is the number of values under consideration).  So, denoting the mean of the values of x by u and the mean of the values of y by t , we get by writing a_i = x_i - u and b_i = y_i - t , ( ∑ ( x_i - u)^2 )( ∑ ( y_i - t)^2 ) ≥ ( ∑ ( x_i - u)(y_i - t) )^2 , i.e. , by definition, { n.var(x) } { n.var(y)} ≥ {n.cov(x,y)}^2 , so that   var(x) var(y) ≥ {cov(x,y)}^2 ; this is the proof of the inequality in case of Bivariate Analysis you may also extend it for probability distribution.

Comment: Sorry for late comment. You haven't used prob. density functions in  your notation for variance and covariance but I think these are equivalent. I think you would need a double sum if there was a different no. of $y_{i}$s say with $x_{j}$s.